# Parse math input in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I'm looking for a library to parse math expressions in OCaml. Specifically, this is for a derivatives calculator I'm making.

For instance, it should be able to parse and interpret `x^2 + 5x + 3` or something similar. I'm wondering if there's a library for this already - I found `Lexing` when googling but I'm not sure it fits my needs?

Comment: For what if worths, https://github.com/ivg/matkit, feel free to use as you want

Answer (score 1):

In OCaml, there is `ocamllex`+`ocamlyacc` for parsing: https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lexyacc.html

You can scroll down to [their complete example](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lexyacc.html#s%3Alexyacc-example), a "desk calculator".
The parser (`parser.mly` in their example) defines the correct syntax, the lexer (`lexer.mll` in their example) defines the semantics.

Comment: (As you can see in this complete example, the `Lexing` module provides support for the lexical analyzers generated by `ocamllex`.)

Comment: Menhir is also a good option for parsing purposes.
http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/